# Is it possible to show an attribute value from a node path?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm currently working on a project and having to overlook a particular code for xml&xsl.

I'm not exactly sure if this line of code is correct. Can someone explain me what it does?

```
<xsl:value-of select="/product/price[contains($name, @name)]/@poz" />
```

I do know what `contains` does.

However i don't know what the rest of the line does, and i can't check it because there's lots more code in the project and other errors. 
Is it possible for someone to explain me a bit how this line works?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
<xsl:value-of select="/product/price[contains($name, @name)]/@poz" />
```

gets the value of the `poz` attribute of a `price` element which is a child of the root element `product` and where a variable named `$name` contains (a substring of) the value of its `name` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!!